# 'There can be only one type with an [Application]' error when attempting to build .NET MAUI android app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maui

I am in the process of migrating a Xamarin.Forms app to .NET MAUI, and I am currently fixing build errors as part of the official migration guide published by Microsoft here:
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Migrating-from-Xamarin.Forms-(Preview)

Currently, I am attempting to fix the build errors that appear with the Android version of the app, but when I attempt to build now, I am getting the following errors:

```
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.476\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1438,3): error XAGJS7009:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestDocument.CreateApplicationElement(XElement manifest, String applicationClass, List`1 subclasses, TypeDefinitionCache cache)
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.476\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1438,3): error XAGJS7009:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestDocument.Merge(TaskLoggingHelper log, TypeDefinitionCache cache, List`1 subclasses, String applicationClass, Boolean embed, String bundledWearApplicationName, IEnumerable`1 mergedManifestDocuments)
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.476\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1438,3): error XAGJS7009:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.Run(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.476\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1438,3): error XAGJS7009:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.RunTask()
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.476\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1438,3): error XAGJS7009:    at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17
```

However, there is only one type in my project that has the [Application] attribute, which is the MainApplication class.  The app shouldn't even be using Xamarin.Forms at all, which is why this is puzzling to me.

Comment: Is there any class inherited from the Application in your xamarin.forms project?

Comment: It's not a Xamarin.Forms project, it's a .NET MAUI project that was migrated from Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: What I mean is there any class inherited from the Application before you migrated. And you can try to clean and rebuild the project.